# Refine code. Search Strings

Tags: java, string

So the code I have is for a homework assignment where the user inputs a sentence (string) and I need to search through the string and return the smallest word. However, there must be a number inputted at the first spot in the string. Ex: "4 WHAT IS THIS". Output should be "IS" and ignore the number. The only way I figured out how to ignore the number is to make the loop skip over the first spot where the number would be. It works by itself but whenever I put it into the rest of my program it stops working. Is there anyway to make this program cleaner?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Lexicographically smallest word
    String TheSentence = sc.nextLine();
    String[] myWords = TheSentence.split(" ");
    int shortestLengths, shortestLocation;
    shortestLengths = (myWords[1]).length();
    shortestLocation = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < myWords.length; i++) {
        if ((myWords[i]).length() < shortestLengths) {
            shortestLengths = (myWords[i]).length();
            shortestLocation = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myWords[shortestLocation]);
}
```

Comment: what about a sentence like "123a abc ab3", is the shortest word "a", "abc", "ab" or "ab3"?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `for` loop (that should start at `i = 0`), add code like this:

```
try {
  double value = Double.parseDouble(myWords[i]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // add the rest of your code here
}
```

The idea is that you try to transform your word to a number and if you fail, it means it's not a number, so you can use the length logic on the word.

Comment: Along with the answer , do not forget to make `shortestLocation = 0;` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to create the function you want to use instead of mixing the relevant code for the exercice with things like reading a line from the input stream.

You can test whether a character is a letter using `Character.isLetter(char)`.
A good exercice is to build a solution using only that function and looking at each character separately (`String.charAt(int)` method) in a loop.
The solution is to remember where the currently shortest word starts and how long it is.

---

In practice, I would just use regexes like this:

```
public static String shortestWord(String sentence) {
  String shortest = null;
  Pattern word = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
  Matcher m = word.matcher(sentence);
  while (m.find()) {
    String candidate = m.group();
    if (shortest == null || shortest.length() > candidate.length())
      shortest = candidate;
  }
  return shortest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using substring, e.g.

```
String result=inputString.substring(1)
```

'1' being the second letter in the string, substring returning every value save for the first.

Answer (score 0):

The below basically just shortens up your code..other than that it doesn't change much. That being said..it would be much better to create all this in a method called shortestWord() or something. There is really no reason the code below shouldn't work though.

Revised Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] myWords = (sc.nextLine()).split(" ");
    int shortestLocation = 1
    for (int i = 2; i < myWords.length; i++) { // No reason to start at 1 as you have
                                               // already made shortestLocation = 1
        if (myWords[i].length() < myWords[shortestLocation].length()) {
            shortestLocation = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myWords[shortestLocation]);
}
```

Suggested Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] myWords = (sc.nextLine()).split(" ");
    System.out.println("The shortest word is: " + shortestWord(myWords));
}

public static String shortestWord(String[] myWords) {
    int shortestLocation = 1
    for (int i = 2; i < myWords.length; i++) { // No reason to start at 1 as you have
                                               // already made shortestLocation = 1
        if (myWords[i].length() < myWords[shortestLocation].length()) {
            shortestLocation = i;
        }
    }
    return myWords[shortestLocation];
}
```